# requestPermission: How to wait until granted?

Tags: android, android-permissions

Android API 23 and above requires that "dangerous" permissions be confirmed at run-time. In accordance with other StackOverflow suggestions, I check for required permissions using `checkSelfPermissions()` and if required, call `requestPermissions()`. That works fine, but the request is handled asynchronously, i.e., `requestPermissions()` returns immediately. The problem is that my app goes on its merry way after `requestPermissions()`. Sometime later, the permission confirm dialog(s) appear but by that time, my app has tried API calls that fail.

I assume I need to wait until all permissions have been granted before proceeding in my app. I guess I could implement some polling kluge to do this but that's just too crude for me. **What is the "Best Practice" to get around this?** Various Best Practice descriptions in the documentation do not address this issue.

Comment: @Afshin OP just wants to wait for the result.

Comment: @TheWanderer oops, I thought he meant he wana bypass permission checking. I delete my comment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put your logic in its own function(s), outside of `onCreate()`.

```
private void doStuff() {
    //whatever
}
```

If the permissions are granted, just call that function directly from `onCreate()`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //...
    if (checkSelfPermissions(/*whatever*/) {
        doStuff();
    } else {
        requestPermissions(/*whatever*/);
    }

    //nothing dependent on runtime permissions after this point
}
```

Then override `onRequestPermissionsResult()`:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == /*whatever you set in requestPermissions()*/) {
        if (!Arrays.asList(grantResults).contains(PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED)) {
            //all permissions have been granted
            doStuff(); //call your dependent logic
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. I guess you are suggesting that I wrap my entire app processing  in onRequestPermissionsResult. I'll try that.

Comment: No, I'm suggesting (actually explicitly stating) that you move it into a new function and then call that where needed.

Comment: Yes, I actually did exactly what you suggested - I guess I just summarized it poorly.

Comment: How could you do this when your `doStuff()` function needs arguments? Is it possible to pass arguments somehow to the `onRequestPermissionsResult`?

Comment: @Filip you should ideally be requesting permissions before gathering any data or setting any state. If that doesn't work, you'll have to use member variables to store data and use it in the method.